# What data structure to use for regexped result in Python?

Tags: python, regex, data-structures, struct

I parsed log file and now I have regexped result for every status:

```
'/status1'
'/status2'
'/status3'
```

For every result I need to keep some info : **num1, num2, num3**

What data structure to use in Python that I could use **array of statuses** in format:

```
/status1, num1, num2, num3
/status2, num1, num2, num3
/status3, num1, num2, num3
```

that I could use some calculation later with these **nums** for every **status**

Comment: tuple of `(str, int, int, int)`

Comment: During calculation I need to change nums, so tuple is not correct way to use. Also I need to create array. I added these details in question.

Answer (score 0):

There are no "arrays" in Python, often when we talk of an "array" in Python context, we refer to NumPy array (this is not what you want here). But Python has lists that can hold objects of different types, thus it is feaseable to have e.g.:
`[[str, int, int, int],[str, int, int, int],...]`
which might be what you need.

Not sure if it helps, I'd rather add it in a comment, but my account is not allowed to add comments yet.